# SimpleImage.php (Again) no errors but not working

Tags: php, file-upload

Ok I have seen many posts on this script. Which can be found.....

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

However I still can not make it work with what I have got.  So here is the problem.  First of all I upload the image and save the name to the database.  I then pass its ID to the next page to retrieve the image and its path from the database.  This is where the script comes in. I then run the image through the script and send you to the success page.

Now the image is not being resized!  The code is not erroring (even with error reporting on).  It would seem the code it just get ignored completely. The image is still there and displays how it was uploaded but the size just hasnt changed.  Im asuming Im using it in the correct way.  Here is the code after the image has been uploaded.

```
$Fetchq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE imageID ='".$_GET['image']."' ") or die('error stuff here');
$fetched = mysql_fetch_array($Fetchq);


$path = "/members/images/members/merseyside/{$fetched['imagename']}";


include('SimpleImage.php');
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load('$path');
$image->resize(60,60);   
$image->save('$path');



 $url = "/activity-photos.php?uploaded=true";        
header("Location: $url");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've had enough of banging my head against this code wall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$image->save('$path');`

If you use a variable inside single quotes, it treats it as an actual string not the variable value.

Solution:

`$image->save( $path ); // Remove the quotes`

or

`$image->save( "$path" ); // Replace with double quotes`

EDIT:

Also, be sure to change `$image->load()` as well

```
...
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load( $path ); // Removed quotes
$image->resize(60,60);   
$image->save( $path ); // Removed quotes
...
```

You can learn more about string interpolation here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: thank you for your reply @tehlulz.  I done that but still no changes.  The image uploads fine then the resizing gets ignored completely and the ini error reporting shows nothing

Comment: Sorry, change it with the `$image->load()` method as wel.

Comment: yeah I did both but nothing @tehlulz.  I have also tried removing the quote completey.  Ive tried changing the path to the full url path. ive tried single quotes.  Can the server stop you changing image sizes or is it definatly a code error?

Comment: can you do a `var_dump( $image );`

Comment: I managed to get the errors but I dont understand them.  Here they are

Comment: Think you forgot to post them :P

Comment: Warning: getimagesize(/members/images/members/Merseyside/0b12dd48f09fafc2e2985743cca2029flazy-grass-2.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in/members/clubs/SimpleImage.php on line 30

Comment: thats just the first of about 7 but I think they all follow that one

Comment: funny thing is the same path is used to display the image straight after the code

Comment: its trying to load the root of the file system. for reading. Which is invalid. It needs to be a direct file path to the image (as if you are going to navigate to it via explorer)

Try just removing the / from the start so its just members/images/...

Comment: I cant thank you enough its fixed!!!!!!!!!!!! Im so happy thank you thank you thank you. just putting {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']} at the start of the path fixed it!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. If you're happy with my answer, be sure to click the tick ;)

Comment: Im very happy where is this tick?